# Paragraph Span Class and h3 Are The Same Hex Code, But Are Showing Up As Different Colors

Tags: html, css

For elements in my #vocational div, I want the h3 and the span class for my paragraphs to be the same color.

Essentially, what I have displayed in my #vocational div is a series of tweets. I want the hashtags and the name and @username of the tweet owners to be the same exact color, but even though the hex code is the same they are showing up as different colors.

Why is this? Should I be using paragraph for what I'm using h3 for? What could I do to make the colors the same?

Example of What I'd Like the #vocational div to look like:

[image: Vocational Div Design]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
    src: url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
  .clearfix:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#calltoaction {
  background-image: url("calltoactionbackground.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#calltoaction p {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  width: 500px;
}
#functions {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#functions p {
  color: #62CE9C;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  color: #62CE9C;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h3 {
  color: #00AF78;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.hashtag {
  color:  #00AF78;
}
#hero {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#herotext {
  float: left;
}
#hero h1 {
  width: 470px;
}
#hero img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#hero p {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 500px;
}
input, select, textarea{
    color: #62CE9C;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    color: #62CE9C;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #62CE9C !important;
}
 
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
#save {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 400px;
  width: 800px;
}
#savefood {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}
#savefoodimage {
  float: right;
}
#savefoodtext {
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 290px; 
}
#savemoney {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savemoneyimage {
  float: left;
}
#savemoneytext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#savetime {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savetimeimage {
  float: left;
}
#savetimetext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#searchbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 300px;
}
#searchbutton {
  background-color: #28C787;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}
#searchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #00BE8B;
}
#tweetone {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetone img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetonetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
#tweettwo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweettwo img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweettwotext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
#tweetthree {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetthree img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetthreetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#vocational {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1120px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#vocational h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}
#vocational p {
  color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hero">
      <div id="herotext">
        <h1>Make the Most of your Food With Pantree</h1>
        <p>Pantree for iOS lets you search for recipes based on the ingredients you already have in your home.</p>
        <form id="form">
          <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
          <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <img src="images/phone.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="functions">
      <div id=save>
        <div id="savemoney">
          <img id="savemoneyimage" src="images/savemoney.png"/>
          <div id="savemoneytext">
            <h2>Save Money</h2>
            <p>Pantree finds you recipes containing ingredients you already have in your home, saving you from unecessary trips to the grocery store.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="savefood">
          <img id="savefoodimage" src="images/savefood.png"/>
          <div id="savefoodtext">
            <h2>Save Food</h2>
            <p>Pantree keeps track of expiration dates, alerting you when food will go stale so you can use it before it goes bad.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="savetime">
          <img id="savetimeimage" src="images/savetime.png"/>
          <div id="savetimetext">
            <h2>Save Time</h2>
            <p>Pantree's built-in kitchen organizing system helps you monitor all of the food in your home, so figuring out what food you have is quick & easy.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="vocational">
      <h1>These Folks Could Use Pantree Every Day</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetone">
            <img src="images/tweetone.png"/>
            <div id="tweetonetext">
              <h3>Kat</h3>
              <h3>@devicat</h3>
              <p>I have no idea what to make for dinner. I am so bad at this game. <span class="hashtag">#adulting</span></p>
            </div>          
          </div>  
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweettwo">
            <img src="images/tweettwo.png"/>
            <div id="tweettwotext">
              <h3>Jack Falahee</h3>
              <h3>@RestingPlatypus</h3>
              <p>Dear Mom, How do I organize my kitchen? Love, me</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetthree">
            <img src="images/tweetthree.png"/>
            <div id="tweetthreetext">
              <h3>mason ryan</h3>
              <h3>@MasonTheManiac</h3>
              <p>Something in my fridge smells really bad.... <span class="hashtag">#cantfindit</span></p>
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="calltoaction">
      <h1>Manage your Kitchen, Effortlessly</h1>
      <p>Pantree makes it easy to find recipes, keep track of food, and organize your kitchen.</p>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its of the same color as of `<h3>`, the difference is in the `font-weight`.

**`<h3>`** has `font-weight: bold;`, while

**`.hashtag`** has `font-weight: normal;`

---

Use bold font on `.hashtag`:

```
.hashtag {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
    src: url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('radomir_tinkov_-_gilroy-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
  .clearfix:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#calltoaction {
  background-image: url("calltoactionbackground.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#calltoaction p {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  width: 500px;
}
#functions {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#functions p {
  color: #62CE9C;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
  color: #62CE9C;
  font-family: 'gilroysemibold';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
h3 {
  color: #00AF78;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.hashtag {
  color:  #00AF78;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#hero {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  height: 600px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#herotext {
  float: left;
}
#hero h1 {
  width: 470px;
}
#hero img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
#hero p {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 500px;
}
input, select, textarea{
    color: #62CE9C;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    color: #62CE9C;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #62CE9C !important;
}
 
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
 
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: #62CE9C !important;  
}
p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
#save {
  float: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 400px;
  width: 800px;
}
#savefood {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}
#savefoodimage {
  float: right;
}
#savefoodtext {
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 290px; 
}
#savemoney {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savemoneyimage {
  float: left;
}
#savemoneytext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#savetime {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}
#savetimeimage {
  float: left;
}
#savetimetext {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 330px;
}
#searchbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 300px;
}
#searchbutton {
  background-color: #28C787;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}
#searchbutton:hover {
  background-color: #00BE8B;
}
#tweetone {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetone img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetonetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
#tweettwo {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweettwo img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweettwotext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
#tweetthree {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 208px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#tweetthree img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#tweetthreetext {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 450px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#vocational {
  background-color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1120px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#vocational h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}
#vocational p {
  color: #62CE9C;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hero">
      <div id="herotext">
        <h1>Make the Most of your Food With Pantree</h1>
        <p>Pantree for iOS lets you search for recipes based on the ingredients you already have in your home.</p>
        <form id="form">
          <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
          <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <img src="images/phone.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="functions">
      <div id=save>
        <div id="savemoney">
          <img id="savemoneyimage" src="images/savemoney.png"/>
          <div id="savemoneytext">
            <h2>Save Money</h2>
            <p>Pantree finds you recipes containing ingredients you already have in your home, saving you from unecessary trips to the grocery store.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="savefood">
          <img id="savefoodimage" src="images/savefood.png"/>
          <div id="savefoodtext">
            <h2>Save Food</h2>
            <p>Pantree keeps track of expiration dates, alerting you when food will go stale so you can use it before it goes bad.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="savetime">
          <img id="savetimeimage" src="images/savetime.png"/>
          <div id="savetimetext">
            <h2>Save Time</h2>
            <p>Pantree's built-in kitchen organizing system helps you monitor all of the food in your home, so figuring out what food you have is quick & easy.</p>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="vocational">
      <h1>These Folks Could Use Pantree Every Day</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetone">
            <img src="images/tweetone.png"/>
            <div id="tweetonetext">
              <h3>Kat</h3>
              <h3>@devicat</h3>
              <p>I have no idea what to make for dinner. I am so bad at this game. <span class="hashtag">#adulting</span></p>
            </div>          
          </div>  
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweettwo">
            <img src="images/tweettwo.png"/>
            <div id="tweettwotext">
              <h3>Jack Falahee</h3>
              <h3>@RestingPlatypus</h3>
              <p>Dear Mom, How do I organize my kitchen? Love, me</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="tweetthree">
            <img src="images/tweetthree.png"/>
            <div id="tweetthreetext">
              <h3>mason ryan</h3>
              <h3>@MasonTheManiac</h3>
              <p>Something in my fridge smells really bad.... <span class="hashtag">#cantfindit</span></p>
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="calltoaction">
      <h1>Manage your Kitchen, Effortlessly</h1>
      <p>Pantree makes it easy to find recipes, keep track of food, and organize your kitchen.</p>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="yourname@email.com"/>
        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Get Early Access" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea how I didn't catch that.

Comment: @AlisonDyer It's my pleasure!

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I have done/seen, I would recommend that when you are linking the CSS file to your HTML file, that you use

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

As opposed to...

```html
 <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Because when I ran it with what I corrected it to, I got all of it to be the same font.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPpAe.png)

Comment: How is this a solution to the problem?

Comment: When I did it using the original code it wouldn't work, so I re-ordered it and it worked with the remain code?

Comment: For my class my professor is making us using Cloud9, Cloud9 forces you to do that when using CSS.